# Want To Fix RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

My blog rss feed is located at - Online Income Startup
    http://www.onlineincomestartup.com/
But the feed is not being detected in some sites. Please guide me on how to fix the feed to make sure everything is working fine.

Comment: Perhaps feedburner might have helped. But unfortunately Google stopped the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add this in the head tag:

```
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://www.onlineincomestartup.com/feed/" title="Online Income Startup" />
```

Comment: thanks.where exactly i have to paste this?new in wordpress actually

Comment: Go /wp-admin -> Appearance -> Editor, find Header(header.php), and put the line just after </title>

Comment: Thanks.I have added that exactly there.Still Some of the aggregators (or whatever you would call it) is not picking up the feed. This is one example -

Dr.Spencer Jones | IndiBlogger
http://www.indiblogger.in/blogger/47805/
The bottom latest posts by Dr.Spencer Jones should pick my posts automatically from the feed, but mine is not working...

Comment: I am sorry it seemed I miss your point, you think there's something wrong with your feed, but it's ok. see this: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onlineincomestartup.com%2Ffeed%2F

Comment: Thanks.It shows valid.so whats the main problem then?please help

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, but I think there might be something wrong with the feed reader, it's not your problem.